# Is it valid to call matrix multiplication a "transformation"

Tags: matrices, functions, terminology

According to Wikipedia, a Transformation is defined as follows:

> In mathematics, a transformation is a function $f$, usually with some geometrical underpinning, that maps a set $X$ to itself, i.e. $f : X → X$.

With that said, consider the following

$$
g(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}, \quad\forall\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n\\ 
$$
where, $\mathbf{A}$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, and $m > n$. Therefore, $g(\mathbf{x}) \in \mathbb{R}^m$, or equivalently we can say that $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$. However, since $\mathbb{R}^m\nsubseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, would it be valid to call the above equation a "Transformation" of vector-space?

Comment: I would rather call that a "map", but that is only psychological. "Transformation" is also perfectly OK

Comment: It's very common for a word have different definitions in different areas or context.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro If we are being pedantic for a moment, matrix multiplication shouldn't be called a linear "Transformation", instead (as you said) could be called a linear-map.

Comment: If we accept this definition of "transformation" , the multiplication with a non-square matrix is clearly not a transformation.

Comment: @mihaild Yeah, but we have fixed the context/area in this case: functions over vectors. So, the terminology used for functions (in-general) should be valid regardless of the nature of the functions' domain/co-domain or the functions' use-case.

Comment: The function $g$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: I agree with @MorganRodgers. I don't think it's that deep. I tend to interchange the words "mapping" and "transformation." As long as the context is clear, there shouldn't be an issue.